# Pymongo поиск и сортировка не повторяющихся элементов ('dict' object has no attribute 'sort')

Tags: python, сортировка, mongodb, pymongo

Существует такой массив в монгодб:

```
_id:5a0f6c61d1154f2f9983ad74
name:"cola"
weight:"2"
status:"+"
time_exp:2017-11-18 00:37:31.946

_id:5a0f6c61d1154f2f9983ad74
name:"pepsi"
weight:"3"
status:"+"
time_exp:2017-11-18 00:37:31.946

_id:5a0f6c61d1154f2f9983ad74
name:"cola"
weight:"3"
status:"+"
time_exp:2017-11-18 00:37:31.946
```

Из него мне бы хотелось найти все элементы по условию `"name": "cola", 'status': '+'`,отсортировать не повторяющиеся элементы, приравнять данные элементы к новой переменной.

То есть: с выше указанного массива выдернуть все "weight" (2 и 3) и для каждого создать свою переменную. К примеру: `n=2, k=3`

Я пытаюсь это сделать так: `db.some_db.find_one({}, {"name": "cola", 'status': '+'}).sort({'weight':1})`, на что получаю ошибку `'dict' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Заранее благодарю за ответы и извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Comment: https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/319200/#3 там внизу описано, как нужно сортировать